# How do I make an ASP.NET MVC checkbox in the view trigger an action method in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am looking for a method in my controller to be triggered when the user clicks on a checkbox in my view.

I have looked at similar answered question regarding this however, none of the solutions have worked.

My view markup is as follows:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Answers)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Number of Votes")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Tick to Vote")
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Answers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Answer
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.AnsCount
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.Hidden("myURL", Url.Action("AddVote", "PollModelsController"))
                <input type="checkbox" name="Vote" id="Vote" unchecked />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Vote').change(function () {
            sendToController();
        });
    });

    function sendToController() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myURL",
            data: ?,
            dataType: "bool",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    };
</script>
```

My controller code is as follows:

```
public ActionResult AddVote(PollAnswersModel answer)
        {
            if (answer.Active.Equals("True"))
            {
                answer.Active = true;
                answer.AnsCount =+ 1;
            }
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
        }
```

In the Controller, I am looking to add on a vote to the 'AnsCount' variable when the user clicks on a checkbox. It will then refresh the page to show the new amount of votes an option will have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must bind the checkbox's ':checked' event in javascript to an ajax call to your controller's action. If the ajax call succeeded, you then use js to to reload the page.

If you don't want to use js, then turn your checkbox into an input (type=submit) and embed it in a form. When the user clicks the input, a form will be posted to the chosen action, which in turns returns a this.View("MyViewName").

**Edit**

Here is an example using JQuery, based on you edit:

Html/JS:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   @if(answer.HasVotes)
{
<input type="checkbox" name="Vote" id="Vote" checked data-id="@item.Id" />
}
else
{
<input type="checkbox" name="Vote" id="Vote" unchecked data-id="@item.Id" />
}   
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#Vote').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var answerId = $this.data('id');
        var url = null;
        if($this.is('checked')){
           url = `/UpVote?answerId=${answerId}`;
        }
        else{
           url = `/DownVote?answerId=${answerId}`;
        }
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url ,
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    })
   });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     return this.View(new AnswerViewModel(this.AnswerRepository.GetAll()));
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpVote(Guid answerId)
{
     //Retrieve the answer that has been voted for
     Answer answer = this.AnswerRepository.FindById(answerId);
     //Add the vote
     answer.UpVote();
     //Save changes
     this.AnswerRepository.SaveChanges();
     // Return 200 OK
     return this.Ok();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DownVote(Guid answerId)
{
     //Retrieve the answer that has been voted for
     Answer answer = this.AnswerRepository.FindById(answerId);
     //Add the vote
     answer.DownVote();
     //Save changes
     this.AnswerRepository.SaveChanges();
     // Return 200 OK
     return this.Ok();
}
```

What will happen is that upon clicking the checkbox, an Ajax call will be made to the UpVote/DownVote action, passing it the arguments you need to retrieve the answer and upvote it (in this case, I passed the answer's ID, stored in a data-id html attribute). If the action succeeds, it will return a 200 OK, which in turns will make JS hit the success function. The latter reloads the page, and your page is re-rendered with the refreshed answers, displaying to the end user the answers that have been voted for.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Charles. I have never used JS before and have looked up similar methods but I am unsure exactly what I am doing. I have updated my code above to include the script that I have included so far if you could kindly fill in what I need.

Comment: Hey @DylanPJ1998! I updated my post to give you a working example of what I think you are trying to achieve. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @DylanPJ1998. Did my edit answered your question? If so, please mark it as the answer ;)